# memory error by using rbf with scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory, probability, probability-density

I want to plot some points with the rbf function like here to get the density distribution of the points:
[image]

if i run the following code, it works fine:

```
from scipy.interpolate.rbf import Rbf  # radial basis functions
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# import data
x = [1, 1, 2 ,3, 2, 7, 8, 6, 6, 7, 6.5, 7.5, 9, 8, 9, 8.5]
y = [0, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 9, 2, 3, 3, 2.5, 2, 8, 8, 9, 8.5]
d = np.ones(len(x))
print(d)

ti = np.linspace(-1,10)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(ti, ti)

rbf = Rbf(x, y, d, function='gaussian')
jet = cm = plt.get_cmap('jet')
zz = rbf(xx, yy)
plt.pcolor(xx, yy, zz, cmap=jet)
plt.colorbar()

# Plotting the original points.
plot3 = plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', markersize=5)  # the original points.

plt.show()
```

Now I want to change my input data:

```
# import data
input = "testProbe.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(input)   # load the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert it to grayscale
# threshold the image to reveal light regions in the gray image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 145, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

x, y = np.where(thresh > 0)
d = np.ones(len(x))
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../Python/pythonprojects/03a_test_rbfWithScipy.py", line 32, in <module>
    rbf = Rbf(x, y, z, function='gaussian')
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\rbf.py", line 220, in __init__
    self.nodes = linalg.solve(self.A, self.di)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\rbf.py", line 226, in A
    r = self._call_norm(self.xi, self.xi)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\rbf.py", line 236, in _call_norm
    return self.norm(x1, x2)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\rbf.py", line 118, in _euclidean_norm
    return np.sqrt(((x1 - x2)**2).sum(axis=0))
MemoryError
```

The error message appears really fast and when I look at the task manager, the PC is not running at full capacity. He issues this message immediately. Something can't be right then, can't it?

I tried it with other threshold values `thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]` to get less values and it works although I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\...\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\rbf.py:220: LinAlgWarning: 
scipy.linalg.solve Ill-conditioned matrix detected. Result is not guaranteed to be accurate. 
Reciprocal condition number2.246772e-22 self.nodes = linalg.solve(self.A, self.di)
```

Any ideas?

If I only cut out a small part of the picture, then it works too. Maybe it makes some preliminary calculation for the memory and gives me the memory error

Comment: Have you tried increasing the threshold value such that, the `rbf` function uses few points? How big is the image in pixels?

Comment: @jadelord The image has 1600x1200 px. I will try to increase the threshold. Thanks!

Comment: @jadelord I tried it with other threshold values and it works although I get the following error message: `C:\Users\...\Python\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\rbf.py:220: LinAlgWarning: scipy.linalg.solve
Ill-conditioned matrix detected. Result is not guaranteed to be accurate.
Reciprocal condition number2.246772e-22
  self.nodes = linalg.solve(self.A, self.di)`

Comment: I got something similar (for my problem), but it was a division by zero. May be the threshold level was too extreme. I have two alternative solutions. I will answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me `Rbf` interpolation is quite computationally intensive and leads to `O(N^2)` operations (correct me if I am wrong). So in order to avoid memory error you can do one of the following, instead of

```
zz = rbf(xx, yy)
```

**1. Iterate with nditer**

Slow, but works for small arrays:

```
for iz, ix, iy in np.nditer(
    [zz, xx, yy],
    flags=['external_loop', 'buffered'], 
    op_flags=['readwrite']
):
    iz[...] = rbf(ix, iy)
```

**2. Use dask.array**

Faster option and uses threads

```
import dask.array as da

n1 = xx.shape[1]
ix = da.from_array(xx, chunks=(1, n1))
iy = da.from_array(yy, chunks=(1, n1))
iz = da.map_blocks(rbf, ix, iy)
zz = iz.compute()
```

Hope this works for you.

**P.S**: As suggested on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865378/) and [scipy docs on Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html), `Rbf` also allows you to replace the `norm` calculation function with a `callable` (see [LowLevelCallable](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.LowLevelCallable.html) and the [Pythran blog](https://serge-sans-paille.github.io/pythran-stories/the-capsule-corporation.html)). It is a bit involved, but it might also solve your problem, while increasing the performance as well.

**P.P.S**: I managed to speedup by a factor of 50 by making this modification:

```
import numpy as np

def euclidean_norm_numpy(x1, x2):
    return np.linalg.norm(x1 - x2, axis=0)

rbf = Rbf(x, y, d, function='gaussian', norm=euclidean_norm_numpy)
```

Comment: thank you! I tried your second option and it's 10s faster! But if I want to run my big image the memory error appears again.

Comment: I am glad it works at least that much. Play with the `chunks` parameter until it can fit in your memory. I am also contemplating to use [other interpolation schemes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation). `Rbf` is extremely slow for my application.

Comment: can you please explain what that code does? So I can better understand and play with the parameters.

Comment: @Dark: See (https://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array.html) Dask is a multithreading/multiprocessing framework. It breaks up a large array which does not fit in the memory into chunks.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand what it does! :)

Comment: So if I understand the chunks right, the array is divided into columns?

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. But are you doing with norm? I read it in the dokumentation but I don't understand it

Comment: I tried the `euclidean norm numpy` from you, but it didn`t speed up my code.

Comment: `chunks=3` is for me optimum. Maybe it helps you too

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Changing the chunk size did help, but it is problem dependent, not a thumbrule. I am surprised that changing the norm didn't rip more speed for you. You can adopt my [Jupyter notebook](https://gist.github.com/ashwinvis/af9bd4cfab95395ca14de35201233043) and see for yourself.

Comment: If i try your link this error message appears: `Sorry, something went wrong. Reload?`And I know it is problem dependet and thank you for your help :) Additionally I reduced the pixels to speed it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177806/discussion-between-jadelord-and-dark).